# Ставится ли точка после кавычек, перед которыми стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак?

Tags: пунктуация

Я читал много книг, в каждой пишут по-своему.
Вот что я нашёл в Правилах-56:
*Примечание 1. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит знак вопросительный, или восклицательный, или многоточие, то те же самые знаки не повторяются после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста, могут ставиться перед закрывающими кавычками и после них, например:

**Читали ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?»**

Но:

**Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».***

У Розенталя:
*Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак, то тот же самый знак не повторяется после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста, ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками и после них. Например: **Читали ли вы статью в «Известиях» «Куда мы идем?»** Ср.: **Бойцы двинулись в атаку с криком «Вперед!».** Когда был выдвинут лозунг **«Вся власть Советам!»?***
Объясните мне, пожалуйста, как следует понимать фразы: "если они требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста", "если они требуются по условиям контекста"? Я не понимаю значения данных фраз!

Answer (score 6):

Ну на вопрос о смысле фраз ответить просто. Речь о том, каким знаком заканчивается сама фраза, внутри которой стоит что-то в кавычках.
А вот насчет точки...
Вы каким изданеием Розенталя пользовались?
Я далек от корректорских дел, но хорошо помню рекомендацию точки в подобных случаях не ставить. Или ошибаюсь, или что-то изменилось. Попробую поднять источники, но чуть позже, сейчас некогда, может кто-то опередит.

Да, вот смотрите [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76).

И вот:
*В конце фразы после закрывающих цитату кавычек: 
...
в) не ставят никаких знаков, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением (таковы, как правило, все цитаты после двоеточия, отделяющего их от предшествующих им слов цитирующего): 
Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»*

[gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_76)

Не знаю, ответил ли на ваш вопрос и надо ли ставить точку на самом деле, но по крайней мере убедился, что у меня не глюк.

Answer (score 3):

***Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».***
Простое невосклицательное по интонации предложение. После него нужна точка. Но оно включает в себя приложение — название пьесы, представляющее собой восклицательное неполное предложение. Таким образом, первая часть предложения требует точки как знака завершения невосклицательного предложения, а приложение требует восклицательного знака. Две части одного целого требуют разных знаков. В этом смысл фразы ***"если они требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста".*** Части текста здесь — это части предложения.
Тот же смысл вкладывается во фразу "если они требуются по условиям контекста".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Извините, Артём, но Вы сделали **_неудачную_** правку! А именно: в предложении, представленном Екатериной, точка в конце предложения НУЖНА, а Вы ее изничтожили. Правильно: **Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».** Без **этой точки** в конце предложения ответ Екатерины не имеет смысла. Извините — ещё раз.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: простите, Римма, но ведь если после цитаты продолжается предложение, точку после неё не ставят. А то, что после него нужна точка, когда оно самостоятельное предложение, Екатерина дальше написала. Такая вот тонкость.

Comment: Мне думается, что ТАК теперь понятно всем. Нет?

Comment: Отличное решение! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Бойцы двинулись в атаку с криком «Вперед!».

Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»

Разница между этими предложениями в том, что в первом случае нет прямой речи. Поэтому в конце точка. Во втором предложении - прямая речь. Поэтому нет точки.