# Нужно ли после прямой речи ставить точку?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Нужно ли в данном примере после кавычек ставить точку?
**И тут же волнение охватило его: «Где же мой фонарик?!».**

Answer (score 4):

Этот вопрос вызывает определённые затруднения в связи с нечеткостью действующих Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации (1956 г.).
С одной стороны в большинстве примеров точка после закрывающей прямую речь кавычки не ставится, если перед кавычкой стоит какой-либо пунктуационный знак (см. §196). С другой - в §135 справочника по правописанию и стилистике Д. Э. Розенталя изложен единственный критерий, по которому завершающий фразу знак может опускаться после кавычек:

*Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак, то тот же самый знак не повторяется после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста, ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками и после них.*

Таким образом, случай точки после кавычки, перед которой стоит восклицательный или вопросительный знак, не подпадает под действие единственного регламентирующего правила.
Этот вопрос неоднократно обсуждался на форумах и на справочных ресурсах, но единого мнения нет. Даже Справка на Грамоте дает взаимоисключающие рекомендации.

Насколько могу судить, сейчас точка в подобных случаях обычно опускается после прямой речи - и сохраняется во всех остальных случаях (лозунг, название статьи и т. п. или цитата, не оформленная как прямая речь). Но этот факт никак не может трактоваться как узаконенная норма, поэтому в ответственных случаях (тест на грамотность, например) я бы эту точку сохранил.

Сходный вопрос был еще [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA).

Comment: Большое спасибо за потробный ответ

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем предложении после кавычек точку ставить не надо, так как прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным и восклицательным знаками.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки после закрывающих прямую речь кавычек зависят от того, как оформлено предложение.

В предложениях с прямой речью слова автора практически всегда — повествовательное невосклицательное предложение. После них, если они начинают предложение, ставится двоеточие, которое требует паузы перед прямой речью и (почти всегда) интонации конца предложения. Двоеточие в этом случае уже осуществляет функции точки. Зачем нам ставить точку после прямой речи, которая может представлять собой восклицательное или вопросительное предложение, и после неё перед закрывающими кавычками стоит восклицательный или вопросительный знак?

Другое дело, если двоеточия после слов автора в предложении нет. Тогда и после закрывающих кавычек может быть точка:
*После звонка все ринулись из класса с криком "Ура!".*
Здесь "Ура!" — это несогласованное определение. Предложение повествовательное, невосклицательное. В конце предложения ставим точку. Именно такие предложения имеет в виду Д.Э. Розенталь, когда пишет:
"Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак, то тот же самый знак не повторяется после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста, ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками и после них. Например: Читали ли вы статью в «Известиях» «Куда мы идем?» Ср.: Бойцы двинулись в атаку с криком «Вперед!». Когда был выдвинут лозунг «Вся власть Советам!»?"

Comment: Но ведь во всех приведенных Вами примерах не прямая речь, а дословно процитированные слова. А вопрос был о прямой речи. Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: Я ответила во втором абзаце, что точка не нужна. Это предложение с прямой речью, с двоеточием после слов автора. 
В третьем абзаце я попыталась объяснить, когда точка после закрывающих кавычек ставится, если перед ними стоит восклиц. или вопр. знак.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна. Мне корректор в газете всегда убирает точки после прямой речи, и не важно, какие знаки препинания стоят внутри кавычек.

Comment: Вы знаете, корректор - это не аргумент. При всем к ним уважении. Есть старый корректорский анекдот о том, как надо писать слово "идти": "Это смотря на каком этаже". В известном москвичам здании "Правды" размещалось несколько редакций (если не путаю, ибо сейчас их там давно уже нет). Так вот, на разных этажах предлагалось три варианта. "Идти", "итти" и "ийти". Дело, правда, происходило до 56 г.

Answer (score 0):

Мильчин  11. Цитаты

**11.7.3. Отсутствие знака препинания после закрывающих цитату кавычек**
Знак препинания не ставится:
1. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, восклицательный или вопросительный знак, а цитата, заключенная в кавычки, является самостоятельным предложением (таковы, как правило, все цитаты после двоеточия, отделяющего их от слов цитирующего). Например:
Печорин писал: “Я не помню утра более голубого и свежего!”
Печорин признавался: “Я иногда себя презираю...”
Печорин спрашивает: “И зачем было судьбе кинуть меня в мирный круг честных контрабандистов?”

Comment: Знак препинания не ставится:2. Если перед закрывающими цитату кавычками стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а цитата не является самостоятельным предложением и после всей фразы с цитатой должен был бы стоять вопросительный или восклицательный знак. Например:
Лермонтов восклицает в предисловии, что это «старая и жалкая шутка!»

Comment: 11.7.2. Точка после закрывающих цитату кавычек



2. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, восклицательный или вопросительный знак, но цитата не является самостоятельным предложением (выступает как член того предложения, в которое включена; обычно такие цитаты — часть придаточного предложения). Например:

Гоголь писал о Манилове, что “на взгляд он был человек видный...”.

Comment: doom, это все так, но не имеет прямого отношения к разбираемому случаю.

Comment: У Розенталя: Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки, а также многоточие ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками, а точка после них. Например: Наконец, я ей сказал: «Хочешь, пойдем прогуляться на вал?» (Лермонтов); Лежа на тюке и плача, он дергал руками и ногами и шептал: «Мама! Мама!» (Чехов); Закричали: «Двоих... Санитары... Гляди, гляди – еще летит... Лезь под вагоны...» (А.Н. Толстой); Хозяйка очень часто обращалась к Чичикову со словами: «Вы очень мало взяли» (Гоголь).