# Перед кавычками восклицательный знак

Tags: пунктуация

В их руках плакаты: «..!», «..!». (элемент предложения)

На двери висела записка: «..!» (прямая речь)

Такие примеры были в архиве сайта Института русского языка им. Виноградова.

Речь шла о том, когда не ставить в конце предложения точку, если перед кавычками восклицательный знак.

А если так:

На двери висели записки: «..!», «..!». 
Здесь тоже в кавычках элементы предложения?

Comment: — Дед Андрей в таких случаях говорил: «Бог на помощь!» — сказал я, подходя к Виктору.

"Дед Андрей в таких случаях говорил: «Бог на помощь!»", — сказал я, подходя к Виктору.
во втором примере нужна ли запятая перед тире?

Comment: Из ответа справочной службы русского языка на Грамоте:
В предложении с прямой речью, которая стоит после авторских слов и заканчивается восклицательным или вопросительным знаком, точка в конце не ставится.

Но слова "Бог на помощь!" произносит не автор (я), а дед Андрей. Тогда это правило не работает и запятая ставится?

Answer (score 2):

1) Одно и то же предложение можно оформить двумя способами:

а) Как предложение с прямой речью, при этом используется стандартное оформление и собственная интонация прямой речи, а именно: понижение тона после слов автора (обозначается двоеточием) и повествовательная, вопросительная или восклицательная интонация в конце прямой речи (обозначается точкой/запятой, вопросительным или восклицательным знаком).

б) Как предложение, в котором нераспространенная прямая речь является членом предложения – подлежащим, дополнением, несогласованным определением.В этом случае прямая речь не имеет собственной интонации и вписывается интонационную модель всего предложения. Прямая речь заключается в кавычки, но двоеточие перед ней не ставится.

В) Оба варианта могут иметь прямую речь в виде однородного ряда.

РЕШЕНИЕ

В их руках плакаты «..!», «..!». (элемент предложения). Предположение: двоеточие не надо ставить.

На двери висела записка: «..!» (прямая речь)

2) "Дед Андрей в таких случаях говорил «Бог на помощь!»", — сказал я, подходя к Виктору. Заключенная в кавычки восклицательная прямая речь в качестве члена предложения встраивается в предложение с основной прямой речью, двоеточие не ставится.

3) Точка после восклицательного знака может ставиться при цитировании, например: Основной темой первой части сборника Блока «Ночные часы» является тема полнейшей безысходности, для которой характерна только «неизвестность, гибель впереди! ».

Answer (score 1):

Если прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным или восклицательным знаком, в независимости от ее положения, точка после нее не ставится.  Ср.примеры: Лежа на тюке и плача, он дергал руками и ногами и шептал: " Мама! Мама!" ( (Ч.); Дедушку знаешь, мамаша?" -  матери сын говорит.  - (Н.);Что же, Наталья, про мужа не слыхать? - перебила кашулинская сноха,обращаясь к Наташке ( Ш).

Дополнение.

[Ставится ли точка после кавычек, перед которыми стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA)