# Правильны ли знаки препинания? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, многоточие

Рассматривая причудливых форм облака в иллюминаторе, вспоминал, как неделю назад, сидя в кресле агентства по продаже авиабилетов, спонтанно составлял маршрут предстоящей поездки: «…А если, к примеру, через Восточный Тимор…?» — «Билет обойдется в 127 тысяч рублей». — «Вариант отменяется…»

Гложут сомнения по поводу правильности расстановки знаков препинания.

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно за исключением такой технической тонкости, что в случае многоточия после знаков, отличных от точки, ставят две точки ***после*** знака (так, чтобы всего было также три знака):

*«...А если, к примеру, через Восточный Тимор?..»*

Ещё не совсем понятно, оправдано ли такое количество многоточий.

Comment: Многоточия в начале и в конце означают, что это фрагмент диалога, а не вся беседа полностью. А после "Восточного Тимора" многоточие - пропущенное слово. Скажем, слово "полететь". А точка в конце, вроде как не нужна...https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/Ставится-ли-точка-после-кавычек-перед-которыми-стоит-вопросительный-или-восклиц

Comment: Конечно же точка в конце не нужна! Это же надо было такое сморозить! А "полететь" я бы всё же дописал. Это, по-моему, так же неудачно, как сократить, не дописав две буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы оформила воспоминания таким образом (в форме диалога).

Рассматривая причудливых форм облака в иллюминаторе, вспоминал, как неделю назад, сидя в кресле агентства по продаже авиабилетов, спонтанно составлял маршрут предстоящей поездки:
«— А если, к примеру, через Восточный Тимор?..
— Билет обойдется в 127 тысяч рублей.
— Вариант отменяется...»

1. Мне кажется, что в первом троеточии нет необходимости, так как вы приводите только тот кусочек текста, который вспомнился.
2. При сочетании вопросительного или восклицательного знака с многоточием знаки эти ставятся на месте [первой точки](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/): *— Сейчас зайдем к старику, так?..*  (Шукш.)
3. Концовку можно оформить и так (с точкой после кавычек):
   — Вариант отменяется».
4. Пример ([Е. Звёздная. Шепот в темноте](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=592034&p=10)).
   *Вспомнилось услышанное:

   «— Ты втянул нас в войну, Повелитель.

   — Нет. Она человек, соответственно, кровная месть невозможна. Ни один из кланов не сочтет похищение человечки достойным поводом. Войны не будет. Я обещал это, становясь во главе народа Истэка, я сдержу слово».*

Comment: Вариант, растянутый на неск. строк не подходит, я им не пользуюсь. Многоточия в начале и в конце означают, что до того были вопросы-ответы и после - тоже. Если это  понятно без многоточий - могу их убрать. Про старика пример не в тему: у меня слово пропущено (вместо него - многоточие): попробовать, полететь, двинуть и т. д. Возможно, по правилам вопр. знак до многоточия, но по смыслу - иначе.