# Ставить ли точку после кавычек побудительной цитаты?

Tags: пунктуация

В тексте необходимо употребить цитату с восклицанием. После закрывающих её кавычек должна ли стоять точка? По мнению проверяющего она не нужна. Та же история с названием:

> «Буржуи негодуют!». История уникального проекта.

Стоит ли ставить точку после кавычек, или требуется её убрать по «классической» схеме?

Comment: Ясно, что вопрос не о кавычках, и всё же определитесь: в тексте ваша конструкция, или — в названии материала?

Comment: я посчитала, что ситуация идентична, так как проверяющий в ситуации с точкой после кавычек с побудительной цитатой заставляет убирать знак в заголовке, так как он там не нужен (компьютерная программа выделяет, да и все пунктуационные схемы, которые он приводит в качестве довода, точек не содержат), а на вопрос про схожую ситуация в тексте просто отмалчивается

Comment: Если правка искажает Вашу мысль, не принимайте её. Очень трудно порой (при обилии слов) понять суть. К тому же в комментарии всё нужное есть.

Comment: Если вопрос решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Comment: Тут товарищ behemothus утверждает, что «Буржуи негодуют!» — это название проекта. Уточните, пожалуйста, так ли это?

Comment: Уважаемый автор! Вы не могли бы  текстовый материал Вашего вопроса представить в более понятной форме, например так: 1)  Заглавие с цитатой. 2) Предложение  из текста с цитатой. Контекст тоже не помешает. В противном случае я перестала понимать, что мы здесь обсуждаем. Нам в большей степени нужно даже не описание вашего текста и вашего понимания данной проблемы, а САМ ОРИГИНАЛЬНЫЙ ТЕКСТ.

Comment: *Уточните, пожалуйста, так ли это?* - @oleedd а вам мало того, что написано?! ***Та же история с названием:  «Буржуи негодуют!». История уникального проекта.***.

Comment: @behemothus Это название материала, а не проекта, согласно оригинальному тексту вопроса. shampar всё поковеркал.

Comment: @oleedd вы окончательно запутались. То, что стоит в кавычках, - название в любом случае. Даже если это и цитата (хотя я не вижу причин так считать), но это все равно **название**.

Comment: @Юлия в отличие от остальных участников я не считаю, что контекст здесь критичен. Правила пунктуации в исходном виде не содержат никаких упоминаний о мотивах кавычек. Цитата ли, название - все одно. Есть два предложения, которые уже сами по себе создают нужный контекст. Между ними должен стоять знак. Для меня важно другое. Чем ваш проверяющий мотивировал свое мнение? Если ничем, покажите ему цитируемый мной кусок из правил-56. Понятно, что он сразу не согласится, но очень интересно, что он скажет.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен (точки в конце второго предложения нет)

Я бы оформила заглавие так:

***«Буржуи негодуют!» История уникального проекта***

Почему?

1) Если почитать Розенталя, то можно увидеть, что **многоточие,** вопросительный и восклицательный знак **ставятся по одинаковым правилам.**

Если говорить **о кавычках при цитировании,** то принцип здесь следующий. Точка после кавычек не ставится, если фраза в кавычках является **самостоятельной** структурой и ставится, если она является **частью другой структуры**.

В частности при оформлении цитаты по принципу прямой речи, она образует самостоятельную структуру. Сравнить (постановка точки после многоточия): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=165#pp165

Если цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, **не является самостоятельным предложением**, то после нее **ставится точка**: М. В. Ломоносов писал, что «красота, великолепие, сила и богатство российского языка явствует довольно из книг, в прошлые века писанных…».

Если же цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, **является самостоятельным предложением**, то после кавычек **точка не ставится** (как при прямой речи): В. Г. Белинский писал: «В “Онегине” все части органически сочленены…»

2) В нашем случае цитата является **самостоятельной структурой,** поэтому точка после кавычек не нужна, если цитата заканчивается восклицательным знаком (также многоточием, вопросительным знаком).

Comment: А вы поняли, что "Буржуи негодуют" - это вообще не цитата (в терминологии автора), а  ***название***?

Comment: Что касается вашего приема (по сути дела - "по аналогии"), то он вообще не должен иметь места в подобных случаях, разве что в правилах реальная лакуна. Но у нас-то её нет, тут другое - противоречивость правид для конкретной ситуации.

Comment: Да, я поняла, что это название. Я исхожу из того, что это самостоятельная единица, а не часть другой конструкции. Четких правил по этой ситуации нет, но можно воспользоваться общим принципом.

Comment: А после самостоятельной единицы точка как раз ***должна*** стоять. И правило я цитировал в своем ответе.

Comment: @Sharon Вряд ли это название. Оригинальный текст: *«Буржуи негодуют!» История уникального проекта, который позволяет нам реально экономить*. Это художественный приём по типу "назло фармацевтам", "врачи ахнули".

Answer (score 1):

1. Во всем согласна с рассуждениями *Sharon*, кроме одного: **точка в конце заголовка не ставится.**

Из справочника издателя и автора ([А. Мильчин](https://books.google.ee/books?id=N2p6GFY7PXkC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=df9B4vwWIx&sig=ACfU3U26cpWCppXjacQnkZGDpKuJhhaAjw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz_5CDiIDmAhVk-ioKHZ67C9w4ChDoATAIegQIChAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&f=false)).
В заголовке из двух самостоятельных, синтаксически не связанных предложений между ними ставят точку, а в конце, по общему, правилу точку опускают.

**«Буржуи негодуют!» История уникального проекта**

«Буржуи негодуют!» — это отдельное самостоятельное предложение, представляющее собой цитату, которая заканчивается восклицательным знаком. Точка после цитаты не нужна.

Без восклицательного знака точка между предложениями нужна.
**«Буржуи негодуют». История уникального проекта**

Вот похожие примеры.
«Русские идут!» Почему боятся России? (книга Л. Вершинина);
«Русские идут». Как русофобия довела до самоубийства министра обороны США (статья);
«Русские идут!» День народного единства в Москве — со Сталиным и иконами (статья).

2. Из вопроса: "В тексте необходимо употребить цитату с восклицанием".

Если "восклицательная цитата" является **частью** предложения, то пунктуация такая.

Мы читали статью «Буржуи негодуют!».
Неужели вы не читали «Буржуи негодуют!»?

Comment: Это не цитата. Это название проекта.

Comment: @behemothus Да какое название проекта?! Это цитата. И в оригинальном тексте вопроса об этом сказано. Полное название: «Буржуи негодуют!» История уникального проекта, который позволяет нам реально экономить. Цитата как художественный приём.

Comment: Какое-какое. Обыкновенное.  Вы вопрос-то прочитали - или влезли в перекания просто из принципа?

Answer (score 0):

Там никак нельзя ставить точку, так как предложение началось внутри кавычек (большая буква) — и должно закончится тоже внутри. Иначе получается ерунда.

Правило:
После закрывающих цитату кавычек не ставят никаких знаков, если перед ними стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76

Comment: *ам никак нельзя ставить точку, так как предложение началось внутри кавычек (большая буква)* -  это как, простите?!

Comment: Ну чисто логически. Такой пример: если вы начали предложение в скобках - можно ли поставить точку после скобок? С кавычками то же самое. Более того, Грамота утверждает, что точка не ставится, даже если такая цитата в конце другого предложения.

Comment: *если вы начали предложение в скобках - можно ли поставить точку после скобок* - обязательно. Точка  после скобок точка ставится всегда., когда она нужна по общим правилам. Грамоту вы не поняли совершенно. Покажите место, которое вы так интерепретировали.

Comment: ***§ 203. После закрывающей скобки, которой заканчивается предложение, ставится знак препинания, требуемый предложением в целом, независимо от того, какой знак может стоять перед закрывающей скобкой***, например: Единственный сын его, дед мой Лев Александрович, во время мятежа 1762 года остался верен Петру III, не хотел присягнуть Екатерине – и был посажен в крепость вместе с Измайловым (странна судьба и союз сих имен!).
Пушкин

Comment: Так естественно. Предложение же не начиналось в скобках, и его нужно закрыть точкой. А у нас предложение **начинается в кавычках**. До них ничего нет.

Comment: Вак - естественно - мне нет. В правилах тоже ничего такого нет. Вы вообще о каком предложении-то говорите?

Comment: О примере с вашего правила. А потом о «Буржуи негодуют!». — Здесь у меня начало предложения до кавычек и его нужно закрыть точкой.

Comment: У вас может быть что угодно. А в грамматике предложение начинается **до кавычек**.

Comment: Ваш ответ — один против трёх. Как-то так.

Comment: Да я не о об ответе. Ум них-то есть какая-никая аргументация (ошибочная, разумеется). А вы просто решили примазаться, не понимая смысла.

Comment: У меня такая же аргументация — кавычках самостоятельное предложение, имеющее свой знак. А после кавычек знак опускается.

Comment: Вот я и говорю что вы не поняли ничего. У Шарон - самостоятельная единица. То есть кавычки входят  в её состав.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку возникли совершенно непонятные вопросы, предваряю ответ небольшим разъяснением. 
После **названия** в кавычках точка ставится. Тут даже и разговора нет. 
Споры возникают только если речь идет о цитате.

> Стоит ли ставить точку после кавычек, или требуется её убрать по
>   «классической» схеме?

Если речь идет о цитате, то по "классической схеме" - вроде бы не нужна. 
Но в вашем случае я  бы эту точку сохранил. 
Основываясь вот на этом.

> Примечание 1. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит знак
>   вопросительный, или восклицательный, или многоточие, то те же самые
>   знаки не повторяются после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они
>   требуются в силу характера соответствующих частей текста, могут
>   ставиться перед закрывающими кавычками и после них, например: Читали
>   ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?» Но: Драматический кружок
>   готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».

П-56 (§ 200)
http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp

Вообще вопрос крайне спорный. 
[Ставится ли точка после кавычек, перед которыми стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4222)

Формулировки того правила позволяют по-разному его трактовать.

Да, "Справка" менее категорична, она говорит лишь о цитатах, а не о кавычках вообще, как в П-56.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76

При этом приведенное в справке "правило" оспаривается само по себе, но даже если принять его за постулат, остаётся масса вопросов. Первый из них: а что считать цитатой?

====

Тут появилось мнение, что дескать правило-де не описано. ну так оно и у Розенталя есть.

> Неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста,
>   ставятся и после закрывающих кавычек:
>
> Я читаю роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?».
>
> В каком стихотворении М. Ю. Лермонтова есть слова: «Люблю Отчизну я,
>   но странною любовью!»?

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178#pp178
§ 66. Кавычки и другие знаки. п. 4.

===

С форума Грамоты.

> Вопрос. **"В бой!"(.) История фронтовой газеты** - что делать с
>   точкой.
>   Ответ. Здесь два предложения. Первое изъяснительное,
>   название газеты, в конце должна стоять точка. То, что в названии
>   газеты есть вскл знак, не отменяет точку в конце.
>
> "В бой!". История фронтовой газеты "В бой!" (история фронтовой газеты)
>   "В бой!": история фронтовой газеты
>
> Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит знак вопросительный, или
>   восклицательный, или многоточие, то те же самые знаки не повторяются
>   после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются в силу
>   характера соответствующих частей текста, могут ставиться перед
>   закрывающими кавычками и после них, например: Читали ли вы роман
>   Чернышевского «Что делать?» Но: Драматический кружок готовит к
>   постановке пьесу «В бой!». Отчего вы говорите: «Как бы не так!»?

Чтобы подвести итог. Цитата ли то, что стоит в кавычках, или название - разницы в плане заданного вопроса большой нет. То есть разница может быть, но не для нашего случая. Главное, что это два ***разных*** предложения. Между ними должен быть знак - по условиям контекста.
Все остальное - от лукавого.

К сожалению, как уже сказал, в правилах по этой части есть противоречие. В § 200 есть примеры, где точка опушена  (хотя это и не оговаривается). Но цитируемое примечание из того же параграфа не оставлят вариантов для нашего конкретного случая. Нигде, ни в у Лопатина, ни У Розенталя, ни у Мильчина (по цитируемым здесь отрывкам) этот момент не отрицается.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101411/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus------).