# Знаки препинания после кавычек

Tags: пунктуация

И вновь возник вопрос об употреблении точки после побудительной цитаты, вызвавший жаркие споры, которые (даже с использованием различных методичек и  пособий) не привели к однозначному ответу. Цитата стоит в середине текста, то есть после нее повествование продолжается. Так надо ли поставить эту самую точку? Вот текст: *Потому на вопрос, почему его картинам присущи пустынность и упрощенная горизонтальная композиция, отвечает так: «Оттого, что прямая горизонта досталась мне по рождению!»(.) Художник прошел учебу в Новоалтайском художественном училище, закончил Московский государственный институт имени В. И. Сурикова.*

Answer (score 2):

Был уже [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/11009#11009) об этом. Бегемотус там цитирует Грамоту:

> *В конце фразы после закрывающих цитату кавычек: ... в) не ставят никаких знаков, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением (таковы, как правило, все цитаты после двоеточия, отделяющего их от предшествующих им слов цитирующего): Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»*

У Вас тоже ответ художника можно считать самостоятельным предложением, поэтому ***точка не нужна.***

Comment: Артем, огромное спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Не за что, Юлия!)

Comment: Артем, а это правило действует и в том случае, если продолжением текста будет абзац?

Comment: Конечно, и в этом случае ничего не меняется!

Comment: Премного Вам благодарна, Артем!))